# How to compute $3^9 \pmod {10}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

The solution given was:

$3^9 = (27)^3 = 7^3 = 49(7)  = 9(7) = 63 =  3 $

I understand up to $\ 3^9 = (27)^3  $ But after that I am lost. Can someone explain how to solve this and what is going on here?

Comment: The solution should say $3^9 \equiv 27^3 \equiv 7^3 \equiv 49 \cdot 7 \equiv 9 \cdot 7 \equiv 63 \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$.

Comment: You are asked to compute the **unit digit** of $3^9$, so in every intermediate result, you can simply take the unit digit and continue without the rest of the number. For example: instead of $27$ just take $7$, instead of $49$ just take $9$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $27$ was replaced with a $7$ because $27\pmod{10}=7$. The same concept arose with the $49$ later, as $49\pmod{10}=9$, and likewise $63\pmod{10}=3$. This is why the values greater than $10$ are switched.

Answer (score 3):

$3^2 = 9
\equiv -1 \bmod 10
$.

Therefore
$3^8
=(3^2)^4
\equiv (-1)^4 \bmod 10
\equiv 1
$.

Therefore
$3^9
=3^{8+1}
=3^8 3^1
\equiv 1\cdot 3 \bmod 10
\equiv 3
$.

Answer (score 1):

When computing modulo $10$, all digits except units can be safely dropped.

For example, $7\cdot7\equiv\color{red}49$.

Then $3^3\equiv\color{red}27,3^9\equiv7^3\equiv7^2\cdot7\equiv\color{red}49\cdot7\equiv\color{red}63$.

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to compute the **unit digit** of $3^9$.

So in every intermediate result, you can simply take the unit digit and continue without the rest of the number.

For example:

- Instead of $27$, you can simply continue with $7$
- Instead of $49$, you can simply continue with $9$